# Serialization error in Serdes while running Streams Application

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am writing an application that processes an incoming record of coordinates and monitors them for entry or exit in defined geofences. Intermediately, I am maintaining a state whether the current coordinate is inside/outside a specific geofence using aggregation.

Below is the stack trace of the error while running this:

```
Exception in thread "geofence-events-990be707-d44d-410d-a8a7-b2a3b90cb84f-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000003, topic=vehicle-sensor-data, partition=0, offset=0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:862)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: com.loconav.GeoFenceDTO). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFlatMapValues$KStreamFlatMapValuesProcessor.process(KStreamFlatMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFlatMapValues$KStreamFlatMapValuesProcessor.process(KStreamFlatMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:351)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.loconav.GeoFenceDTO cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.loconav.GeoFenceDTO is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    ... 45 more
```

I wrote a peek after flatMapValues and the first record gets printed and then this exception occurs. Below is the topology code

```
vehicleGeoFences
  .flatMapValues(
      (readOnlyKey, value) -> {
        List<GeoFenceDTO> geoFenceDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
        // some logic
        return geoFenceDTOS;
      })
  .groupBy((key, value) -> value.getGeofenceId() + "," + value.getVehicleId())
  .aggregate(
      GeoFenceDTO::new,
      (key, value, aggregate) -> {

        //setting values
        return geofenceDTO;
      },
      Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), getGeofenceDTOValueSerde()))
  .toStream()
  .mapValues(
      (readOnlyKey, value) -> {
        // changing object
      })
  .to(
      Topics.VEHICLE_EVENTS.name(),
      Produced.with(vehicleEventsKeySerde, vehicleEventsValueSerde));
```

I have written a custom Serde on GeofenceDTO than uses jackson ObjectMapper to convert object to bytes and vice-versa. Somehow it looks parameters provided in the Materialized are not being picked. The default key value Serde for the application is StringSerde.

Help appreciated. TIA. I tried changing custom object to Avro generated but same error persisted.

Comment: That stack trace does not match your program. It's shows `KStreamKTableJoinProcessor` but I cannot see any join in your program.

Comment: I skipped that part. Before this, I am joining a GlobalKTable with a KStream which results in `vehicleGeoFences`. Kindly let me know if I should add that as well.

Comment: I see. It's still unclear which processor is the issue to me. It does not seem to be the aggregation because not corresponding node is in the stack trace. What happens if you remove the final `to()` ?

Comment: group by and aggregate both don't have a stack trace. I thought this was how it's supposed to be. I was suspecting aggregation because GeoFenceDTO is returned by that step and maybe to store the resultant Ktable, it needs to serialize the object and fails in that. That was why I added Materialzed to make it explicit but still nothing. 
I made this work by adding default value serde as GeofenceDTOSerde. but this is hackish and I have yet to find why original didnt work
Even after removing to and restoring to String as default serde, error persists.

Comment: Maybe set a breakpoint in `Serializer #serialize()` to see what topic it tries to write into for further debugging?